# RuntimeError: CUDA error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device (rastervision)

Tags: ubuntu, pytorch, cuda, runtime, nvidia-docker

Hi I am trying to run rastervision pipeline on a GPU NVIDIA GEOFORCE 3050 RTX.

- Ubuntu 22.04
- Pytorch: Version: 1.12.0+cu116
- CUDA: 12

But when I run the Docker container like that:
sudo docker run --rm --runtime=nvidia --gpus all  -it     -v ${RV_QUICKSTART_CODE_DIR}:/opt/src/code      -v ${RV_QUICKSTART_OUT_DIR}:/opt/data/output     quay.io/azavea/raster-vision:pytorch-0.20 /bin/bash

The model does not train and outputs this error:
RuntimeError: CUDA error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call,so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.

PD: running nvidia-smi outputs the characteristics of the GPU, meaning it is recognized.
I would very much appreciate some help in this issue.
Thanks!

This is the output I get:

```
`Skipping 'analyze' command...
python -m rastervision.pipeline.cli run_command /opt/data/output/pipeline-config.json train
Running train command...
2023-03-09 08:53:29:rastervision.pytorch_learner.learner: INFO - Building datasets ...
2023-03-09 08:53:29:rastervision.core.data.raster_source.rasterio_source: WARNING - Raster block size (2, 650) is too non-square. This can slow down reading. Consider re-tiling using GDAL.
2023-03-09 08:53:29:rastervision.core.data.raster_source.rasterio_source: WARNING - Raster block size (2, 650) is too non-square. This can slow down reading. Consider re-tiling using GDAL.
2023-03-09 08:53:29:rastervision.pytorch_learner.learner: INFO - Physical CPUs: 12
2023-03-09 08:53:29:rastervision.pytorch_learner.learner: INFO - Logical CPUs: 16
2023-03-09 08:53:29:rastervision.pytorch_learner.learner: INFO - Total memory:  15.30 GB
2023-03-09 08:53:29:rastervision.pytorch_learner.learner: INFO - Size of /opt/data volume:  445.44 GB
2023-03-09 08:53:29:rastervision.pytorch_learner.learner: INFO - Size of / volume:  445.44 GB
2023-03-09 08:53:29:rastervision.pytorch_learner.learner: INFO - Python version: 3.9.16 (main, Jan 11 2023, 16:05:54) 
[GCC 11.2.0]
/bin/sh: 1: nvcc: not found
2023-03-09 08:53:29:rastervision.pytorch_learner.learner: INFO - 
2023-03-09 08:53:29:rastervision.pytorch_learner.learner: INFO - Thu Mar  9 08:53:29 2023       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 525.89.02    Driver Version: 525.89.02    CUDA Version: 12.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   37C    P3    14W /  30W |    262MiB /  4096MiB |      7%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

2023-03-09 08:53:29:rastervision.pytorch_learner.learner: INFO - Devices:
2023-03-09 08:53:29:rastervision.pytorch_learner.learner: INFO - index, name, driver_version, memory.total [MiB], memory.used [MiB], memory.free [MiB]
0, NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Ti Laptop GPU, 525.89.02, 4096 MiB, 262 MiB, 3639 MiB

2023-03-09 08:53:29:rastervision.pytorch_learner.learner: INFO - PyTorch version: 1.12.1+cu102
2023-03-09 08:53:29:rastervision.pytorch_learner.learner: INFO - CUDA available: True
2023-03-09 08:53:29:rastervision.pytorch_learner.learner: INFO - CUDA version: 10.2
2023-03-09 08:53:29:rastervision.pytorch_learner.learner: INFO - CUDNN version: 7605
2023-03-09 08:53:29:rastervision.pytorch_learner.learner: INFO - Number of CUDA devices: 1
2023-03-09 08:53:29:rastervision.pytorch_learner.learner: INFO - Active CUDA Device: GPU 0
2023-03-09 08:53:29:rastervision.pytorch_learner.learner: INFO - model=SemanticSegmentationModelConfig(backbone=<Backbone.resnet50: 'resnet50'>, pretrained=True, init_weights=None, load_strict=True, external_def=None) solver=SolverConfig(lr=0.0001, num_epochs=1, test_num_epochs=2, test_batch_sz=4, overfit_num_steps=1, sync_interval=1, batch_sz=2, one_cycle=True, multi_stage=[], class_loss_weights=None, ignore_class_index=None, external_loss_def=None) data=SemanticSegmentationGeoDataConfig(scene_dataset='<1 train_scenes, 1 validation_scenes, 0 test_scenes>', window_opts="method=<GeoDataWindowMethod.random: 'random'> size=300 stride=None padding=None pad_direction='end' size_lims=(300, 301) h_lims=None w_lims=None max_windows=10 max_sample_attempts=100 efficient_aoi_sampling=True") predict_mode=False test_mode=False overfit_mode=False eval_train=False save_model_bundle=True log_tensorboard=True run_tensorboard=False output_uri='/opt/data/output/train'
2023-03-09 08:53:29:rastervision.pytorch_learner.learner: INFO - Using device: cuda
2023-03-09 08:53:29:rastervision.pytorch_learner.learner: INFO - train_ds: 10 items
2023-03-09 08:53:29:rastervision.pytorch_learner.learner: INFO - valid_ds: 10 items
2023-03-09 08:53:29:rastervision.pytorch_learner.learner: INFO - test_ds: 0 items
2023-03-09 08:53:29:rastervision.pytorch_learner.learner: INFO - Plotting sample training batch.
2023-03-09 08:53:30:rastervision.pytorch_learner.learner: INFO - Plotting sample validation batch.
2023-03-09 08:53:31:rastervision.pytorch_learner.learner: INFO - epoch: 0
Training:   0%|                                                                   | 0/5 [00:00<?, ?it/s]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/opt/src/rastervision_pipeline/rastervision/pipeline/cli.py", line 251, in <module>
    _main()
  File "/opt/src/rastervision_pipeline/rastervision/pipeline/cli.py", line 247, in _main
    main()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1130, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/src/rastervision_pipeline/rastervision/pipeline/cli.py", line 236, in run_command
    _run_command(
  File "/opt/src/rastervision_pipeline/rastervision/pipeline/cli.py", line 218, in _run_command
    command_fn()
  File "/opt/src/rastervision_core/rastervision/core/rv_pipeline/rv_pipeline.py", line 154, in train
    backend.train(source_bundle_uri=self.config.source_bundle_uri)
  File "/opt/src/rastervision_pytorch_backend/rastervision/pytorch_backend/pytorch_learner_backend.py", line 120, in train
    learner.main()
  File "/opt/src/rastervision_pytorch_learner/rastervision/pytorch_learner/learner.py", line 267, in main
    self.train()
  File "/opt/src/rastervision_pytorch_learner/rastervision/pytorch_learner/learner.py", line 1265, in train
    train_metrics = self.train_epoch(
  File "/opt/src/rastervision_pytorch_learner/rastervision/pytorch_learner/learner.py", line 1188, in train_epoch
    output = self.train_step(batch, batch_ind)
  File "/opt/src/rastervision_pytorch_learner/rastervision/pytorch_learner/semantic_segmentation_learner.py", line 26, in train_step
    out = self.post_forward(self.model(x))
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1130, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torchvision/models/segmentation/_utils.py", line 23, in forward
    features = self.backbone(x)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1130, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torchvision/models/_utils.py", line 69, in forward
    x = module(x)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1130, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/batchnorm.py", line 148, in forward
    self.num_batches_tracked.add_(1)  # type: ignore[has-type]
RuntimeError: CUDA error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call,so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
make: *** [/opt/data/output/Makefile:6: 0] Error 1`
```

Answer (score 15):

This error arises when CUDA code was not compiled to target your GPU architecture. Here, the version of PyTorch the Rastervision Docker image is using does not include CUDA code compiled for `sm_86` (Ampere GeForce).

As a workaround, you can force the reinstallation of a version of PyTorch that contains code for `sm_86`. Once you start your container using `docker run`, run the following command:

```bash
pip install --force-reinstall torch==1.12.1+cu113 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/
```

Comment: This worked like magic. Thank you so much Anis, you really solved my problem!! I also wonder, since I have to reinstall Pytorch (by running the command you provided above) every time I create a container, would there be any way of reinstalling Pytorch outside the container (in my virtual environment, for instance), so that the command doesn't need to be run every time a container is created? Thanks again :)

Comment: My pleasure! It is probably possible but I recommend against it to keep everything contained. However you can create a new Docker image that extends the existing one and add this command, and then you can use this new Docker image when running a new container :)

Comment: Related question?  https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/122158/cuda-error-no-kernel-image-is-available-for-execution-on-the-device-which-p